# \b equivalent for unicode regular expression that maintains zero-width in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, regex-lookarounds

I've read many questions on SO about how to use the regex token `\b` for Unicode text (since \b only detects word boundaries in ASCII text reliably). All the answers (if I'm not mistaken) end up suggesting using some form of lookahead (and/or lookbehind) to find word boundaries in Unicode text.

However, lookaheads are not exactly the same as `\b` in one important way. The `re2` python library requires that you don't use lookaheads in order to compile your regex. The reason for this is that there is no way to compile the regex to a finite-state automata with a lookahead without backtracking.

I've found that a large regex (thousands of characters long) is run against thousands of paragraphs the speed difference is drastic. It takes about 20 minutes with a lookahead and 2 minutes with \b (on ASCII text). The issue is I need to run this regex on Unicode.

My question is, is there an equivalent to \b (at least in Python) that maintains the zero-width property? The zero-width property allows you to avoid using lookaheads since it doesn't consume the space around the match.

Edit:

To explain the use case a bit more, I am doing Named Entity Recognition (per [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) of NER) in Unicode text. For simplicity, I'll give an English example:

> John Bob and Sam went to the store

I have a regex with a list of names. The code to find these 3 names would be

```py
word_boundary = "\b"
reg = re2.compile(fr"{word_boundary}(John|Bob|Sam){word_boundary}")
```

Since `John` and `Bob` are next to each other in the text, we require either

- a zero-width `word_boundary` so the space is not consumed between John and Bob. Currently I only know of `\b` but this will not work for my Unicode text.
- a lookahead so the space is not consumed between John and Bob. I don't want to do this because of the speed cost.

Using `\P{L}` as `word_boundary` would not work here.

Comment: There is no `\b` in Python, there is `\b` as a word boundary in `re` that is Unicode aware (by default in Python 3). If you can match a Unicode letter in RE2, you can always "simulate" a word boundary using something like `(?:^|\P{L})` and `(?:$|\P{L})` or `(?:^|[^\p{L}\p{N}_])` / `(?:$|[^\p{L}\p{N}_])`

Comment: Reading the re2 documentation, I expect the answer is no...

Comment: Logically, `\b` must be implemented as some kind of hard-wired look-ahead. If it's faster than the flexible look-aheads, then it's probably because it's heavily optimised towards the few character combinations that can constitute word boundaries in ASCII. Finding word boundaries in Unicode text is obviously much harder a problem, so it's likely to take significanlty longer to compute.

Comment: What do you mean by "no"? Re2 has support for `\p{L}` (any Unicode letter) and `\P{L}` (any char other than a Unicode letter).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\P{L}` is not zero-width

Comment: @lenz this argument sounds reasonable. Do you have a source?

Comment: No, strictly speaking I've been speculating, based on my experience with comparable problems.

Comment: Why do you want a zero-width pattern? What are you doing? In these cases, you must share your whole relevant code and explain what problem you have. The regex I shared should work for detecting strings that you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have edited my post to clarify my use-case

Comment: You have not explained why you need a non-consuming pattern (btw, you already know it is not possible to use lookarounds with RE2). If you just need - as you say - to **find** named entities, all you need is `reg = re2.compile(r"(?:^|\P{L})(John|Bob|Sam)(?:$|\P{L})")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regex would find `John` and `Sam` but not `Bob`. I think this example perfectly explains why I need a non-consuming pattern.

Comment: It finds all those three buddies, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y68CCh/1) **tested with the RE2 setting**. Note that once a single of those names is found, the result is *TRUE*, there is no need searching for all of them. You say you only need to **find** a match with your regex. You are not looking to *extract all matched substrings*, you are not *replacing the found matched substrings with something else*. Thus, `re2.compile(r"(?:^|\P{L})(John|Bob|Sam)(?:$|\P{L})")` is working and enough to solve the problem you described in the question.What your real problem is still unclear.

Comment: Your example is using a different sentence than the one I gave in my post. Also, Named Entity Recognition is defined by finding *all* named entities in the text, not just if there is one named entity in the text (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)). I've edited my question again even though I don't see what was ambiguous.

Comment: Since there is no lookaround support in RE2, you already know there is no solution. Workarounds depend on what you have already tried, what you are trying to achieve. If you replace, just replace twice. If you extract, simply add a space after every char that is not a letter, digit or underscore, eg. by replacing `([^\p{L}\p{N}_])` with `\1 `. E.g. `re2.findall(r"(?:^|\P{L})(Виктор|Саша|Даня)(?:$|\P{L})", re2.sub(r'([^\p{L}\p{N}_])', r'\1 ', "Виктор Даня Саша Лена 1,s,а-ф+я"))`.

Comment: But, as with all workarounds, you will never get the same performance. Thus, you just should use the right tool for the job: `re` or `regex`.

Comment: Since the answer appears to be a simple "no", it's better to focus on the [overarching issue](https://xyproblem.info/) of performance and ask for assistance on [CodeReview.SE].